# Data Explorer Query: Best answer to question with no accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

I am looking for a pre-made query for Data Explorer that finds all my answers that have the most votes for questions without accepted answer.

Just want to see how many of those I have, and if possible a link to those questions.

Comment: Looking at your SO profile, I have to expect you know at least a little bit of SQL. Why not just write the query yourself and, if you have trouble doing so, ask for help on SO?

Comment: Just not so familiar with the Data Explorer database design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the most elegant answer (I'm not a fan of correlated sub queries), but it works and it's what I came up with first:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/106139/questions-with-no-accepted-answer-where-i-have-the-highest-score?UserID=536086

Answer (score 1):

I've just edited Joel's code, got something that works the way I wanted:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1621/answers-with-best-score-but-question-has-no-accepted-answer

Comment: You might want a LEFT JOIN rather than an INNER JOIN for the last join, otherwise you won't see questions with no other answers (unless that's what you wanted)

Comment: I want only questions that I've answered with the highest score. So there's at least 1 answer to them. questions without answers wouldn't be needed. Thanks